# Create a custom index in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I would like create a index of ".h" files in my doxygen-ed project in addition of the default index.

Is there a way to do this automatically ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there isn't. I think best you can achieve is by placing the include files in a separate directory.

Comment: Thanks @albert, I will look for a manual way...

Answer (score 0):

I have do this by adding a `\addtogroup` in every headers like this :

```
/** \addtogroup Headers
  * - oge-mutex.h
  * \copybrief oge-mutex.h
  */
```

This will create a page with a list of all marked headers and her brief description.